# Convert Chinese character .wav song into .mp3 or .wma on English OS

Tags: mp3

I have bunch of Chinese .wav files on my hard disk that I'm trying to convert into .mp3 with Audacity but it appear that Audacity can not read Chinese character songs but the .wav file display correctly on my 32 bits Win7 Ultimate(English) pc.

I have to rename these Chinese character songs into English file name in order to convert them.

Does anyone know if there is any software (prefer open source) that will take Chinese character file name(.wav) and convert it into .mp3 without renaming the file?

Answer (score 1):

I'll tentatively suggest [Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com).

It can certainly do the format conversion and can handle files with accented characters quite happily. The site itself has a Russian interface, so I'm assuming that the software has too.

There's a free version, but the mp3 encoder is time limited to 30 days. However, you can install your own lame encoder and it will carry on using that without complaining.

What I don't know is how it handles Chinese characters in file names.

Answer (score 1):

Try CDEX
[Download CDEX](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/?q=download)